# Using makefile assignments from a shell script

Tags: shell, text-processing, make

For example:

```
srcdir = ../libc  # Src directory
prefix = /usr/local           // Installation path
```

The first line is from a makefile and second from `config.make`.

I need to access the variable in a shell script as `$srcdir` and `$prefix`.

One solution I found is cutting all `` ` = ` `` to `` `=` `` and the part after `#` and `//` and do `eval`.

Is there any other easy and reliable solution?

I am on `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: Can you post your solution?

Comment: What if you have `scrcir = $(TOPDIR)/src`?

Comment: @Gnouc, solution posted as answer.

Comment: @n.m.Luckly my script will not have to face such situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never try and parse foreign languages in shell script. There can always be some unexpected caveat you'll run into, and it just becomes a nightmare trying to accommodate all scenarios.
Instead, use the native interpreter to parse it and give you what you want.

```
getmakevar() {
    makefile="$1"
    var="$2"

    make getmakevar -f -  <<EOI
include $makefile

getmakevar:
    @echo \$($var)
EOI
}
```

It's POSIX compliant, and will handle any and all possible formats of the makefile (as long as it's valid gnu make)

---

```
# cat Makefile
bar=baz
myvar = /foo/$(bar)

# getmakevar Makefile myvar
/foo/baz
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a pure POSIX sh version. Things I like about it:

- Entirely shell based (no calls to external commands, aside from printf)
- It is general (the shell functions are reusable)
- It imports the definitions into the current environment.

The things I dislike:

- Uses eval. I tried to avoid it, but it is necessary to make the definitions without hard-coding them. I'm validating that the name is reasonable and quoting the value. That should make it safe, but I'm not 100% sure it is.
- POSIX sh is ugly.
- There are no local variables to functions in POSIX sh.

Well, here it is:

```
#!/bin/sh

trim_left() {
    _str=$1 _chrs=$2
    while [ "$_chrs" ]; do
        _chr=${_chrs%"${_chrs#?}"}
        while [ "${_str%"${_str#?}"}" = "$_chr" ]; do
            _str=${_str#?}
        done
        _chrs=${_chrs#?}
    done
    printf %s "$_str"
}

trim_right() {
    _str=$1 _chrs=$2
    while [ "$_chrs" ]; do
        _chr=${_chrs%"${_chrs#?}"}
        while [ "${_str#"${_str%?}"}" = "$_chr" ]; do
            _str=${_str%?}
        done
        _chrs=${_chrs#?}
    done
    printf %s "$_str"
}

trim_comment() {
    _str=$1 _marker=$2
    printf %s "${_str%%"$_marker"*}"
}

quote_str() {
    _str=$1 _qstr=
    while [ "$_str" ]; do
        _chr=${_str%"${_str#?}"}
        if [ "$_chr" = "'" ]; then
            _qstr=$_qstr"'\\''"
        else
            _qstr=$_qstr$_chr
        fi
        _str=${_str#?}
    done
    printf "'%s'" "$_qstr"
}

# [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]
valid_vname() {
    _vname=$1
    case $_vname in
        [[:lower:][:upper:]_]*)
        ;;
        *)
            return 1
        ;;
    esac
    _vname=${_vname#?}

    while [ "$_vname" ]; do
        case $_vname in
            [[:lower:][:upper:]_[:digit:]]*)
            ;;
            *)
                return 1
            ;;
        esac
        _vname=${_vname#?}
    done

    return 0
}

ws='    
'


input_file=$1
[ "$input_file" ] || {
    printf '%s\n' 'usage: script <file>' >&2;
    exit 1
}

while IFS== read -r _name _value; do
    name=$(trim_left "$(trim_right "$_name" "$ws")" "$ws")
    case $_value in
        *'#'*)
            value=$(trim_comment "$_value" '#')
        ;;
        *'//'*)
            value=$(trim_comment "$_value" '//')
        ;;
    esac
    value=$(trim_left "$(trim_right "$value" "$ws")" "$ws")

    if valid_vname "$name"; then
        eval "$name=$(quote_str "$value")";
    fi
done < "$input_file";

echo "$srcdir"
echo "$prefix"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
FILENAME="<path>"
while read LINE
do
    echo "$LINE"
    if echo "$LINE" | grep -E -q "^srcdir*"
    then
        LINE=$(echo $LINE | cut -d"#" -f1) # No Comment, strip part after #
        LINE=$(echo $LINE | awk -F" // " '{print $1;}') # No Comment, strip part after //
        LINE=$(echo $LINE | tr -d ' ')
        srcdir=$(echo $LINE | tr -d '^srcdir=')
        break
    fi
done < "$FILENAME"

echo $srcdir
```

Comment: All these successive calls to `grep`, `cut`, `awk`, `tr` are more complex than this needs to be. You're missing double quotes around many variable substitutions.

Comment: Also, are you sure that the variable you're looking for will always be called `srcdir`? Because that seems too hard-coded for me.

Comment: Let's try this with `srcdi = me` :)